# Kendo grid - error when calling javascript function: "javascript runtime error: 'funcName' is undefined"

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a Kendo grid and I'm trying to test a javascript function call after selecting a row.

```
<div id="datagrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("datagrid_Concessoes")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Code).Title("Código");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Title("Descrição");
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreationDate).Title("Data de Criação");
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreationUser).Title("Criado por");
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 534px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Events(e => e.Change("test"))
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(15)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetConcessoes", "MasterData"))
        )
     )
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
function test() {
    alert("test");
}
```

I get a `javascript runtime error: 'test' is undefined` as soon as the grid is about to be displayed. I tried the lines:

```
.Events(e => e.Change("test"))
.Events(e => e.Change("test()"))
```

but without luck

Comment: Which version of kendo ui and jqeury are you using ?

Comment: Could you try placing the function immediately before the grid & see what happens? It could just be that the function isn't defined yet

Comment: @mo.esmp, `kendoUi` version is the latest and `jquery` is 1.7.1

Comment: @AndrewWalters, I placed it on top of the View and it works! (??!) Why is that? Because I have another function at the bottom of the View code and it is working fine!

Comment: The grid was trying to call the function before it was rendered on the page most likely

Comment: That's a bit odd. It makes sense but shouldn't because I've got another function being called at the bottom. Maybe the grid is rendered before the rest of the page...

Comment: I bet the function that's working is tied to a different event that fires later after everything's loaded up.

Comment: Yes it is, you are right. However, I thought the function would be called when I select a row: after selecting a row, it would see that a "test()" function was called and go look for it on the page. But no, still strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid is probably firing a `Change` event immediately on load, and if your java script functions are all defined at the bottom of the page they may not be available yet.

A work around would be moving the `text()` function up above this grid to ensure it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd but according to a bug report in telerik forum ([Grid row selection change event not firing](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-row-selection-change-event-not-firing)) it works fine with jQuery version 1.7.2. Try version 1.7.2 and see it works or not.

Comment: +1 for the link and suggestion of newer jQuery version